# Programming a GUI Like Steam?

Tags: python, user-interface

So I've been tinkering with a few different GUI's but I haven't been able to even find a point to begin researching this question:

How do I make a GUI like Steam (Digital distribution app) has? More specifically, I'm interested in how they manage to make their SHIFT+TAB menu pop up in-game, without disrupting/pausing/effecting the game. I've been somewhat successful in making a GUI window "stay on top" when a game is in window mode, but Steam pops this little menu up over the top of a running, fullscreen game.

That's what I'm interested in learning about. Any info would be much appreciated. :)

Sorry if this isn't the correct place to post this. I wasn't sure exactly where to ask.

PS> Preferably something I could implement in Python!!!

Answer (score 2):

The Steam overlay/notification system hooks into games via Direct3D or OpenGL in Windows (depending on the game) from my understanding (as it doesn't work for games that aren't Direct3d/OpenGL like Diablo).

It uses the same rendering libraries that the game uses and thus can overlay their menus natively.

As for Python implementations, you can check out http://directpython.sourceforge.net/ and http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/ as a start (for DirectX and OpenGL libraries respectively) but can I warn you that I don't think this is as simple as you're hoping.

Answer (score -2):

Hmm, that looks very much like they are using Adobe AIR or maybe Flash.

Comment: They most certainly are not. Flash does not have anywhere near the capability to do what Steam does. A quick google search will also reveal that steam is written in C++.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'll be much more careful with my "answers" from now on.

Comment: That's ok, I learned that the hard way too, but it makes you a better answerer!